# Raster increase in size when reprojected in R and QGIS

Tags: r, raster, projection, qgis

I'm using a Land cover raster of North America which is publicly available here: https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/4e615eae-b90c-420b-adee-2ca35896caf6

I clipped it in `R` to cover Québec/Labrador:

```r
veg <- raster("CanadaLandcover2015/CAN_LC_2015_CAL.tif")
e <- extent(c(1000000, 2700000, 500000, 2700000))#all qc
veg_qc <- crop(veg, e)
```

The raster is originally in projection `ESPG:3978 NAD83/Canada Atlas Lambert`. I wanted it to be in lat and long to be able to extract the values to datapoints.

```r
veg_qc2 <- projectRaster(veg_qc,crs="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs")
```

That single line took ~12 hours to run and took over 200 GB of Temp data. Worst, there was a warning (sorry did not copy it) and only half the raster showed.

So I decided to try with the function `Wrap` in `QGIS`. Although it worked perfectly, the output raster was 16 Gb! The original clipped raster was only 693 MB.

To make things worse, I need the value layer to be included in `R`, so I used:

```r
veg_qc <- getValues(veg_qc)
```

And I get the following error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 31.0 Gb

1. Why does the raster get bigger when reprojected?
2. Would there be a way to compress the raster or reproject without that giant increase of data?
3. How can I add the values to a big raster layer?

Ultimately, I could clip the raster further with the mcp of my data. I could also reproject my data and my other rasters in `EPSG:3978` (although I am wondering if my other rasters my end up as > 10GB too).

Comment: Hi Laurie Maynard, welcome to SO! I think a better approach would be to (i) transform the projection of the point layer from `EPSG: 4326` (i.e. WGS84) to `EPSG: 3978`, (ii) extract the raster values at the location of the points, and (iii) transform the projection of the point layer back from `EPSG: 3978` to `EPSG: 4326`. Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue this week. After a reprojection, from 40Mb to 350Mb. I found the answer in this link [Huge file size after averaging two rasters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178642/huge-file-size-after-averaging-two-rasters).

What I did in QGIS (not R by this time) is that I opened the following function in the Manu bar: raster > conversion > translate, and in Advanced parameters > Additional command-line parameters, I added `-co COMPRESS=LZW`. This will compress using the LZW method. Also, according to this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/should-gdal-be-set-to-produce-geotiff-files-with-compression-which-algorithm-sh) and considering your dataset, you can use PACKBITS. I hope this helps you.